# What does multiplying of charges means?

Tags: electrostatics, coulombs-law

Today I learned Coulomb's law,

[image]

and I didn't get what does this multiplication $q_1 * q_2$ gives?
I want to understand this visually.

Answer (score 2):

It gives a quantity that is proportional to each of the charges involved independently, so that increasing either one increases the (magnitude of the) force.

$k$ has units of its own, and these include a $\dfrac{1}{[C]^2}$ (inverse coulombs squared) term, so the units of the intermediate quantities in the equation don't lead to any non-physical results.